# Event Binding from within a Blazor Component

Tags: events, components, blazor

googling didn't help me, I hope you can. I have a Modal.razor component like so:

```
<div class="modal" id="@Id">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">@Header</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Body
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            @Footer
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

@code {

```
[Parameter] public string Id { get; set; }
[Parameter] public RenderFragment Header { get; set; }
[Parameter] public RenderFragment Body { get; set; }
[Parameter] public RenderFragment Footer { get; set; }
```

}

On my Links.razor view I've got:

```
    <Modal Id="myModalEdit" >
    <Header>
        Edit Link
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <EditForm Model="@SelectedItem" OnValidSubmit="@Update">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Label:</label>
                <div>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@SelectedItem.Label" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => SelectedItem.Label)" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Url:</label>
                <div>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@SelectedItem.Url" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => SelectedItem.Url)" />
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Notes:</label>
                <div>
                    <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@SelectedItem.Notes" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => SelectedItem.Notes)" />
                </div>
            </div>




            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </EditForm>
    </Body>
</Modal>
```

The Update method works perfectly well when I put the EditForm outside of the Modal Component. How do I make it work inside the Modal Component?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your error log

Comment: No error was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description such as working perfectly well or not working are clearly not helpful.. However, I guess the issue is that the call to the submit button  result in the rendering of the parent component where your Model component resides.

Understand this, the submit button does not really cause the submission of the form data to the server. It does not lead to the tradition post back. Remember, Blazor is a SPA, no post back. As a matter of fact, the submit event is intercepted and cancelled or prevented.

Solution: Use a button with the @onclick directive, such as this:

```
 <button @onclick="Update" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Update</button>
```

Note that the Update method should be defined in the parent component, automatically calling the StsteHasChanged method to re-render your page. If it still does not work, wait for good news...

Comment: Hi Enet, thanks for your answer. I managed to find the flaw... it was the data-dismiss="modal" part of the Update button. I thought that argument was only important for Bootstrap 4 Modal, but obviously, it somehow was cancelling the submitting action, which to me sounds like you described in your second paragraph. Technically, I did not use your solution, but your explanation helped me find the culprit in my code. Thanks again.